# Subbase of the Product Topology

Tags: general-topology

In the book General Topology by Stephen Woolard, it is said that a subbase for the product topology on $\Pi_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ is the collection:

$$S =\big\{\pi^{-1}_\alpha(U_\alpha)|\forall\alpha\in A, U_\alpha \text{ open in }  X_a\}$$

But this will only generate one basic open set of the product topology which are all sets of the form $\Pi_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha$ where $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ and $U_\alpha \neq X_\alpha$ for only finitely many $\alpha\in A$. In other words we can only write a basic open set which uses only one fixed open set in each $X_\alpha$ as the finite intersection of things in $S$.

So in $S$, do we use all the open sets in each $X_\alpha$ and include their inverse projection in $S$?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type out the other conditions I will add them now

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I don't think this definition of $S$ is correct. The $\forall\alpha$ doesn't make too much sense, and $U_\alpha\in X_\alpha$ also seems weird.
Also, I don't really get your question, what's your concern? Maybe you should review the definition of subbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $f:X\to Y$ and $\mathcal B$ denotes a subbase of the topology on $Y$ then: $$f\text{ is continuous iff }f^{-1}(U)\text{ is open for every }U\in\mathcal B$$

---

The product topology on set $X:=\prod _{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ can be defined as the coarsest topology such that all projections $\pi_{\alpha}:X\to X_{\alpha}$ are continuous.

So if $\mathcal B_{\alpha}$ denotes a subbase for $X_{\alpha}$ for every $\alpha\in A$ then in the collection:
$$T:=\{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\mid U_{\alpha}\in\mathcal B_{\alpha}\}\subseteq S$$we can recognize a subbase of the product topology.

For the $\mathcal B_{\alpha}$ there are several choices and one of them is the collection of **all** open sets in $X_{\alpha}$. In that case $T=S$.

---

Every subbase of a topology induces a base containing exactly the finite intersections of sets that belong to the subbase.

Comment: So is the subbase for the product topology constructed as follows (just want to check I understand):

Say $A = \{1,2\}$. Fix $\alpha = 1$. Take the 1st inverse projection ($\pi^{-1}_1$) of all open sets in $X_1$, add these to your subbase. Then $\alpha = 2$ and take the $\pi^{-1}_2 (G)$ for all open sets $G$ in $X_2$. Add these to your subbase.

Comment: Yes, that gives you a subbase of $X_1\times X_2$. I would rather not speak of "the" subbase, but of "a" subbase. There are more possibilities.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

All the other basic open sets which you mentioned may be written as a finite intersection of sub-basic open sets. Here's why.

A basic set of the form $$V = \coprod_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha
$$
is equal to the intersection of all of the sets $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$:
$$V = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} \pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)
$$

However, all but finitely many of the terms $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ are equal to $X$, and each such term may be eliminated from the intersection without changing the value of the intersection.

Thus, the intersection may be rewritten as a *finite* intersection, over the finitely many sets $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ such that $U_\alpha \ne X_\alpha$.

Comment: So are they saying that the union of sets **of the form** of $S$ make up a subbase? Because if we just fix open sets in each $X_\alpha$ we cannot write every basic open set as the finite intersection of these fixed open sets in $S$, i.e. take a basic open set where all $U_\alpha$ are different from the ones we fixed in $S$.

Comment: If the set of unions of elements of $S$ is a subbase, then $S$ is one and the other way around. You really need to read the definition of subbase again.

Comment: I am not saying the set of unions of elements in $S$, I am saying the union of sets like $S$.

Comment: There are saying that the **set** $S$ is a sub-base. To put it another way, the *set* of all sets of the form $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$, such that $\alpha$ is an element of $A$ and $U_\alpha$ is an open subset of $X_\alpha$, is a sub-base

Comment: This is the infinite def. correct?